# Dynamic database connection using parameter available in url - codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to make dynamic database connection based on parameter in url which will be loaded first time. After that  maintain this connection throughout site.Example : maintaining using session or in define variable so that it will maintain connect throghout.

Answer (score 0):

You can very much acheive the same using the `pre_system` hook.

There, you just need to perform the following steps.

1. Check in the session / cookie, if a variable for the db_in_use (whatever suites you) is available or not. If it is available, just dont do anything.
2. If it dose not exists back in the session. Just check the URL, based on the URL, set the variable value and put it in session. Now - you may create a variable which you may use to instantiate a connection with.
3. You may create a base model class where, based on the variable set - you may instantiate the connection for the application and extend each model from the base model created.

This should surely work for you.